# Entity Framework won't detect changes of navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm having trouble with detecting changes of a navigation property:

My testing model looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I've created and saved an object of type `Person` with both `Name` and `Address` properties assigned. My problem is that if I fetch the `Person` object back from the database and I change the `Address` property (ex. to null) then EF doesn't detect the change!

My code is this:

```
using (var ctx = new EFContext())
{
    Person p = ctx.People.First();
    // p.Address IS NOT NULL!
    p.Address = null;
    var entry = ctx.Entry(p);
}
```

Why is `entry.State` **`Unchanged`** ?

**Edit:** If I call `SaveChanges`, the record is saved correctly (the `Address` become null)!

**Edit 2:** I've created the foreign key property as billy suggested. If I inspect the `Person` object in Visual Studio, the `State` is `Modified`. If I don't stop with the debugger inspecting the object's values, the state is `Unchanged`!

**Edit 3:** Loading the `Person` object using `ctx.People.Include(x => x.Address).First();` solves the problem. Is there a way to avoid calling `Include` and continue to modify the `Address` property instead of the `AddressId` one?

Comment: What happens if you call ctx.DetectChanges()?

Comment: Nothing. The result is the same!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all: You MUST follow @billy's advice to use `Include`. Your remark "*p.Address IS NOT NULL!*" is only true because you are watching `p.Address` in the debugger and thereby triggering lazy loading in the debugger, so the change of setting the address to `null` is detected. In release mode or when you don't inspect the properties in the debugger your code wouldn't work and no changes would be saved.

So, the answer to your Edit 3 is: No.

Second: `var entry = ctx.Entry(p)` only returns *entity states* and you didn't change an entity state but instead a *relationship state*, or more precisely you *deleted* a relationship. You can't inspect relationship states with the `DbContext` API but only with the `ObjectContext` API:

```
Person p = ctx.People.Include(x => x.Address).First();
p.Address = null;
var objCtx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;
var objentr = objCtx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted);
```

`objentr` will have an entry of type `RelationshipEntry` now:

[image]

EF will consider this relationship entry together with entity state entries when you call `SaveChanges()` and delete the relationship, i.e. set the `Address` foreign key column of the `Person` in the database to `NULL`.

About Edit 2: Changing a foreign key property (which is a scalar property in your model) is a change of the entity itself, so the entity state will be `Modified` in this case.

Comment: Nice answer, but I have a doubt. How do I identify that an specific entry suffered this changes and not other, because this is a query to the specific context.

Comment: How do you do this in in EF Core, because there's no `ObjectContext`?

Comment: I've been using similar code to track changes for quite a while. Recently I started adding foreign keys to my model. But when I delete an entity, relationships for which I also have a foreign key don't show up in `ObjectStateManager`'s list of deleted relationships. Do you have any idea why that is?

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the Address nav. prop. in your query, otherwise EF won't consider changes to it when you save :

```
using (var ctx = new EFContext())
{
    Person p = ctx.People.Include(x => x.Address).First();
    //p.Address IS NOT NULL!
    p.Address = null;
    var entry = ctx.Entry(p);
}
```

You could also use foreign keys in your model, which I like very much :

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public int? AddressId {get; set;}
}
```

...

```
using (var ctx = new EFContext())
{
    Person p = ctx.People.First();
    p.AddressId = null;
    var entry = ctx.Entry(p);
}
```

Comment: I've tested the solution with DetectChanges but no way.. still got Unchanged state! If I use the int? foreign key I guess it will work right because I'm going to change the value of a "simple" property and not the navigation property directly. In fact if I change the Name property of the Person object everything is Ok!

Answer (score 2):

In my application, before a reload is requested or the user leaves the item/view, I perform some checks to make sure there are no unsaved changes.

This is basically running off the currently accepted answer, but I wanted to provide an implementation and bring to the attention that you must call `Context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` before the `ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager` can pick up relationship changes! I spent quite a bit of time debugging this, silly!

```
_EagleContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_EagleContext).ObjectContext;
var changedEntities = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified);

if (_EagleContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified)
    || changedEntities.Count() != 0)
{
    var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("There are changes to save, are you sure you want to reload?", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == MessageBoxResult.No)
    {
        return;
    }
}

// Continue with reloading...
```