# Retrieving the entities from the ObjectStateEntry when this is a relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I work on my solution based on ASP.NET MVC with EF Code First.

I have the following model classes:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int RequestID { get; set; }
    public virtual string BudgetNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string SiteCustom { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    public string DesignationFr { get; set; }
    public string DesignationNl { get; set; }
    public string DesignationEn { get; set; }
}
```

I need to log user modifications. For example, if user changed the `SiteCustom` value of the Request, I can easily track it with the code below. So inside the SaveChanges I intercept every added & modified entries.

```
    public override int SaveChanges() 
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); // Important!
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        List<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntryList = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified).ToList();

        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)
        {
            if (entry.IsRelationship)
            {

            }
            if (!entry.IsRelationship)
            {
                if (entry.Entity is Request) 
                {
                    var request = (Request)entry.Entity;
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

As you can see in the code above, when the entry is not a relationship, I can easily retrieve the entity behind it.

**My problem:** when the user modified the `Vehicle` property of the request this is a relationship and I didn't succeed to retrieve the entities when this is a relationship. I mean not only retrieve the key values of the 2 parts of the relationship but all the fields of the entities. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You must use `Include` to track the changes. For instance:

```
var re = ctx.Requests.Include(i => i.Vehicle).Where(i => i.RequestID == 1).FirstOrDefault(); //do no use find
//var re = ctx.Requests.Find(1);

 re.Vehicle.DesignationEn = "asdfasdfa";
 re.Vehicle.DesignationFr = "1qweqweqweq";

 ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Context:

```
this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

var entries = objectContext
   .ObjectStateManager
   .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted);

foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    //you can see Vehicle changes here.
}
```

You probably won't face this problem if the LazyLoading is disabled.

Sources:

[Entity Framework won't detect changes of navigation properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670212/entity-framework-wont-detect-changes-of-navigation-properties)

[Entity Framework 4.1+ many-to-many relationships change tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490509/entity-framework-4-1-many-to-many-relationships-change-tracking)

Comment: With the solution you suggested `var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(...)` if I modify `BudgetNumber` which is a string I get an entry BUT if I modify the `Vehicle` which is a relationship I don't get any entries. Any idea why? Because I really need to log any user modifications (especially the Vehicle). Thanks.

Comment: I'll take a look when I get home

Comment: No sorry, probably I was not clear. When I said I modified the `Vehicle`, I mean selected another Vehicle. Not changing it. Let me explain you: I have a list of vehicles (Honda, Hyundai, ...) and I add (a reference to) it on my `Request`. Each time I (remove the old one and) add a `Vehicle` on my 'Request' and run your code, I didn't get anything. But with my own code (see my answer) I got relationship changes (in this case this is an add). But with my code I don't know how to manage the relationship data to retrieve the 2 (tracked) entities (each part of the relationship). Thanks.

Comment: By the way I'll take a look at your second link (Entity Framework 4.1+ many-to-many relationships change tracking) maybe this can be useful.

Comment: The second link you provided points me to the right direction. Many thanks.