# Entity's state is not changed when a collection navigation property is changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This works as expected:

```
var customer = getCustomerFromSomewhere();
customer.Name = "Foo";
context.SaveChanges();
// ...
// ... in an override of SaveChanges, get the entry state
var isModified = entryState == EntityState.Modified;  // ==true
```

The simple property was changed, so the entity is automatically marked as modified by the context.

Now consider a change to a navigation property which is a collection:

```
var customer = getCustomerFromSomewhere();
customer.Orders.Clear();
var order = getOrderFromSomewhere();
customer.Orders.Add(order);
context.SaveChanges();
// ...
// ... in an override of SaveChanges, get the entry state
var isModified = entryState == EntityState.Modified;  // ==false
```

So the entity is not automatically marked as modified in this case. I get around this by manually marking it as modified, but I want it to occur automatically.

How do I do that? How do I detect whether an entity's relationships are modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to [use the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670212/entity-framework-wont-detect-changes-of-navigation-properties), but that didn't work for me until I implicitly forced checking for changes:

```
myContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
```