# Why EF Core does not automatically add entity when binding navigation property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Database-first approach with a single `Table A` which tries to simulate a linked list. With the following columns:

```
- Id (INT)
- Name (NVARCHAR)
- Position (INT)
- NextId (INT)
- PreviousId(INT)
```

Where `NextId` and `PreviousId` are foreign keys to `Table A (Id)` field.

I am trying to insert a new entity between two existing entities.

```
var first = dbContext.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Position == 1);
var second = dbContext.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Position == 2);

var newTask = new Tasks{ Name = "My new task", Position = 2, PreviousId = first.Id, NextId = second.Id};

first.NextIdNavigation = newTask;
second.PreviousIdNavigation = newTask;

second.Position = 2;
dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

This is updating `second` entity `position` but not inserting the `newTask` into the Database, why not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670212/entity-framework-wont-detect-changes-of-navigation-properties/11670457 might be relevant

Comment: I don't find it useful for my issue, since I am using LazyLoading

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also add the `CREATE TABLE` statement to your question.

Comment: Because you did not add it to the Tasks DbContext.

Comment: @funatparties Depending on the code/model that might not be required.

Comment: Maybe `dbContext.Entry(newTask).State = Added` should do the trick?

Comment: @E.Williams `dbContext.Tasks.Add(newTask);` works as well, but it should work already without it, so there might be some issue with your code/model.

Comment: Are you using lazy loading with or without proxies?

Comment: with proxies @StevePy

Comment: Hmm, with Proxies, instead of newing up a concrete instance, possibly try `var newTask = Context.Tasks.Create();` (or `CreateProxy()` depending on version) initializing the values, and set both ends of the bi-directional references. (set newTask.PreviousIdNavigation & newTask.NextIdNavigation as well as the existing entities) Otherwise it does look like what you have should work, assuming you meant `second.Position = 3;`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you configured the `Task` model into database context the right way. As a side note, I would give it another name.

```
    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int? NextId { get; set; }
        public int?  PreviousId { get; set; }

        public Task Next { get; set; }
        public Task Previous { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        private const string DefaultConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = LinkedList";

        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(DefaultConnectionString);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().ToTable("Tasks");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
                .HasOne(t => t.Next)
                .WithOne(t => t.Previous)
                .HasForeignKey(typeof(Task), "NextId")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
             .HasOne(t => t.Previous)
             .WithOne(t => t.Next)
             .HasForeignKey(typeof(Task), "PreviousId")
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        }
    }
```

Moving on, you could do something like this

```
var first = context.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Position == 1);
var second = context.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Position == 2);

if (first is not null && second is not null)
{
   var newTask = new Task()
   {
      Name = "Third Task ",
      Position = 3,
      NextId = second.Id,
      PreviousId = first.Id
   };
   
   context.Tasks.Add(newTask);
   context.SaveChanges();
  
   first.Next = newTask;
   newTask.Next = second;

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

After creating `newTask` it should be marked as `Added`. This can be achieved either by directly modifying its state or by placing it on the contexts `DbSet`. Next, you should commit the transaction (it is important to avoid a circular reference) and then re-establish the pointed entries for the `Next` and `Previous` navigation properties. After that, you can commit the transaction again.

This should be the final result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had already managed to do it by calling `SaveChanges()` two times, but I wanted to avoid it by trying to add the new task throught navigation properties of already existing entities